# How can I set `decorator` on arrow function in `typescript`?

Tags: typescript

I create a decorator in `typescript` like below code:

```
const measure = (
  target: Object,
  propertyKey: string,
  descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
) => {
  const originalMethod = descriptor.value;

  descriptor.value = function (...args) {
    const start = performance.now();
    const result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);
    const finish = performance.now();
    console.log(`Execution time: ${finish - start} milliseconds`);
    return result;
  };

  return descriptor;
};
```

It works fine for a `function method` but doesn't work for `arrow function`.

Below is an example of my arrow function:

```
@measure
const underTest = () => {
...
}
```

It fails to compile because the third parameter `descriptor: PropertyDescriptor` is not optional. I understand that arrow function is considered as a property rather than a method so I can make it compile by declaring the third parameter as optional: `descriptor?: PropertyDescriptor`. But I don't know how to call the arrow function inside my decorator.

Comment: can you add a short example of how you would try to use it on an arrow function? And not directly answering your question, but from my point of view you could also use `const alg = measure(() => { /* alg */ })` for arrow functions instead of a decorator

Comment: I've written [an example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgUwIYQK4CcEBMYF4YA8AKjAgB5QJhYQwAUAdE0ugOYQBcMSYAngNoBdAJR4AfNz5i6wAEZcio3BIDeAWABQMGJigYw9JgxbsuABRZJEldBGJjhXAEoI96MEV4AHBPfEx1LW0YUEhYaBZYfB90ADMQdDgeYAQGMBAAdzphTWCQ8GgdBDQAGyiQ2UZmNggcoO1QwoQSpC8IbDwYGPjE5NT0rNEAWhgI9Chc4MaQEtSSkFY6AAMAUTIEYFQoAEtwGB3ELgASFWbW9qwAXzgIJbq83X0i0omgy813jU1G8NQ4TsQKAw2DodDAf04MHBcFkCHQQiUEmhEAYmCwqBSoLQcAANFDEaM-jAANRQvEABmEdWxdAAguh0EheAxYugQHA6CoYLMwKwoAALLgARnJorFMEuwgYSS8oIAbnjtgSlcIgA) on how you could solve it with only arrow functions

Comment: Thanks for your code. I am looking for a way to use `decorator`. I have added my use case in the question.